# How can I detect if a project has been developed with Microsoft Expression Blend SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, expression-blend

How can I detect if a project has been developed with Microsoft Expression Blend SDK? Is there a special Blend Solution file to open it? A comment in generated files? I don't know this product.

Comment: *why* do you need to know?  If you elaborate on that, we might be able to provide more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking about Blend SDK? The dll's? Or Expression Blend application?

If the former, you can check what dll's are referenced by the project (in csproj file). Most Blend dll's are named like "Microsoft.Expression.*.dll" (I know only one exception: System.Windows.Interactivity).

If the latter, I'm fairly sure that blend adds `<ExpressionBlendVersion />` to project's csproj file. I can't check it right now.

One additional thing - if someone uses Expression Blend and add stuff to the project it does not prevent another developer on another machine (without blend installed) to use the project and develop it further. The only requirement is the Blend SDK (if someone is using blend dll's)

Comment: `ExpressionBlendVersion` is the only way to know if it has been *edited* with blend.  But that doesn't mean someone hasn't removed this tag from the csproj...

Comment: Yes, the tag can be removed at any time (but it will return when the project is open again in blend).

Answer (score 1):

Usually apps are **NOT** *developed* using Expression Blend. Expression Blend is a design tool. However, If a *designer* adds a referense to something containing Microsoft.Expression.... or in the Window your see xmlns directives like:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
mc:Ignorable="d"
```

Its usually has been opened in Expression Blend.

Also if you open your csproj file you'll find something like:

```
<ExpressionBlendVersion>4.0.20901.0</ExpressionBlendVersion>
...
...
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.Expression.Blend.WPF.targets" />
```

Other than that Expression Blend and Visual Studio share solution (.sln) files

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 adds this namespace to new windows and user controls to support the `d:DesignWidth` and height attributes.